# Do I need to get these vents re-sealed? Is roofing cement the wrong thing to seal them with?

Tags: roof, sealing, flashing

I bought a home about a year ago, and one of the things that came up in the inspection was that the inspector thought that certain areas on the roof were sealed incorrectly.  Not that the seals wouldn't work - he seemed to imply that the way they were sealed was an older way of sealing these things and that we should look into getting the seals re done using a more modern technique/materials/what have you.

To quote the inspection report verbatim:

> This is a good installation although the flashings around the plumbing
> vents have been heavily sealed with roofing cement. These areas are
> especially susceptible to leaking and a qualified contractor should be
> enlisted to the flashings replaced.

And here are some photos of the seals in question, from the inspection report:

[image: photo of roof]

I asked a friend of mine who is more knowledgable than I am about these things for a referral to a roofer to get the work done, and when I showed him the pictures and told him what the inspector said, he said he thought it "looked legit" to him, and was wondering if the inspector was making that recommendation just to be able to have something to say in the report, and thought that getting the seals re-done would be overkill.

Can anyone else weigh in on this?  Is the inspector right, and we should get the seals re-done?  Or is my friend right, and the seals are fine and getting them re-done would be overkill?

Comment: My opinion of home inspectors is not very high because of comments like that. They regularly say there are code violations on reports on electrical when there are no violations. I would say the same about this the sealing job works and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It may be worth _paying_ a roofer to come inspect your roof with the explicit understanding up front that if repairs are necessary he _won't_ be getting the job. This will help eliminate any bias on his part to recommend repairs that are marginal or unnecessary, while still making it worth his while to come out.

Comment: I'd would buy some "Black Jack" (what we have here) or a roofing tar and do it myself.  It's pretty cheap and not that hard to use.